Correct notation for matrix and vector repetitions
Given a matrix $A^{w \times f}$. I repeat the matrix $L$ times along the $f$ dimension, resulting in $A'^{w \times Lf}$. What is the proper notation for the repetition operation?

$[A\ A\ \ldots A]$ is often used

As a computer scientist, I don't really like this notation, because it can be interpreted as a 3d matrix $L \times w \times f$. What do you think about this idea: $A'{i,j}=A{i,j \mod L}$?

In mathematics the notation suggested above is common, these are called block matrices. For notation that would be more intuitive to computer scientists that are not mathematicians you should probably ask on the compsci stackexchange or stackoverflow.
